# on trivialisation of T-torsors

Tags: gr.group-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ a smooth connected projective curve over an algebraically closed field $k$ and $F$ its function field. $T$  a $X$-torus.
Let $R$ be any ring.

Let $E$ a $T$-torsor on $(X-x)\times_{k}R$. Does it exists a fppf covering $R'\rightarrow R$ such that $E$ becomes trivial on $Spec(F)\otimes R'$?

Comment: Consider the case $R = k$.  If such an $R'$ exists then by choosing a $k$-point of $R'$ the generic fiber $E_{\eta}$ is trivial, so if true then any $T$-torsor $E$ on $X-x$ has trivial generic fiber $E_{\eta}$ (equivalently, $E$ is trivial over a *Zariski* neighborhood of the generic point of $X-x$). Can you prove this special case?

Comment: By Steinberg theorem any G-torsor on the function field of a smooth curve on an algebraically closed field is trivial.

Comment: And what is $x$?

Comment: $x$ is a closed point on the curve

Comment: @prochet:  Oops, I should have remembered the vanishing result over fields of cohomological dimension 1.  Strictly speaking, I think Steinberg's paper is restricted to perfect fields.  The vanishing over any field of cohomological dimension 1 (such as the function field of a curve over an algebraically closed field, which is imperfect in positive characteristic) is not true for general smooth connected affine groups but is true for connected reductive groups (such as tori); see Remark 1 in section 2.3 of Chapter III of Serre's "Galois cohomology" book. 